# Solving a heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this by separating the temporary variable $t$ from the spatial variables in order to get an eigenvalue problem for $\Delta$ and an ODE in $t$ but I have not been able to achieve it.

$$u_{t}=\alpha^2 \Delta u$$ in $\Omega \times (0, +\infty)$ , $u(0,t)=0, x\in \partial \Omega, t\geq 0$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-empty, open and bounded, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha>0$  is a constant, $u(x,0)=f$ and $f\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$.

Comment: If the boundary is smooth enough, can we extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then use Fourier transform?

Comment: Of course! you can

Comment: The title on the list of Q's is different. It says Hate Equation Solve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(x,t)=F(t)G(x)$, we have $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{F'}{F} = \frac{\Delta G(x)}{G(x)} = \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a constant. Hence, the separated equations are

$ F(t) = F(0) e^{\lambda \alpha^2t} \;\; $ for $t \in (0,\infty)$,

$ \Delta G = \lambda G \;\;$ for $x \in \Omega$.

In general, the eigenfunctions for arbitrary $\Omega$ cannot be explicitly expressed. Also, additional theory (in functional analysis) is required to show that the system has countable infinite of eigenvalues $\{\lambda_0,\lambda_1,...\}$. Finally, one would also need some theory to proof that these eigenfunctions serve as a complete basis of the solution space.

Comment: Your observation is very interesting. Can you solve the problem for $n = 2$ and $\Omega = (0,L) \times (0,L)$?

Comment: Yes, the eigenfunction (with boundary condition $u(0,t)=0$) are in the form of $sin(m_1\pi x/L) sin (m_2\pi y/L)$, with $m_1=0,1,2,...$ and $m_2 = 0,1,2,...$. In this case $\lambda = m_1^2 + m_2^2$.